# Given an outer div and an aspect ratio for an inner div, how do I calculate the maximum size of the inner div

Tags: javascript

I have 2 boxes / divs. An outer box and an inner box. The inner box is always contained within the outer box. Given the following info:

> outer box: width=200 height=100
>
> inner box: aspect ratio=16/9

In JavaScript, how do I calculate the maximum size of the inner box such that its aspect ratio is preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the outer aspect ratio and use that to determine if the inner box needs to be letter-boxed (landscape, shorter) or pillar-boxed (portrait, narrower) relative to the outer box. Calculate the inner dimensions based on that. You can also calculate the offsets needed to center it.

```js
const outerWidth = 200;
const outerHeight = 100;
const aspectRatio = 16/9;

let innerWidth, innerHeight, innerTop, innerLeft;

if (outerWidth / outerHeight > aspectRatio) {
    innerWidth = outerHeight * aspectRatio;
    innerHeight = outerHeight;
    innerLeft = (outerWidth - innerWidth) / 2;
    innerTop = 0;
} else {
    innerWidth = outerWidth;
    innerHeight = outerWidth / aspectRatio;
    innerLeft = 0;
    innerTop = (outerHeight - innerHeight) / 2;
}
```

Comment: This really helped and I will accept this answer. The only fault I could find with this is that it seems to only work with this change ... innerHeight = outerWidth / aspectRatio ... see my answer with working code example

Comment: @danday74 You're correct. The aspect ratio needs to be inverted (`9/16`) in that scenario and changing `*` to `/` effectively does that. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I know you're asking for JavaScript specifically, but this is pretty [simple to do in CSS with `aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio), and if you need the dimensions in JS you could just grab the rendered dimensions.

```js
const pre = document.querySelector('pre');
const aspect = document.querySelector('.ratio');

// getboundingClientRect also works.
const dimensions = window.getComputedStyle(aspect);

pre.textContent = `width: ${dimensions.width}, height: ${dimensions.height}`;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.ratio {
   aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
   /* Just keeping it within the constaints */
   max-height: 100px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.no-ratio {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="ratio">
    16:9
  </div>
</div>
<pre></pre>

<div class="container">
  <div class="no-ratio">
    Not 16:9.
  </div>
</div>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Thanks and I'm sure this will help some people but for my purposes I need the values from the calculation. However, your answer is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
let outerBoxWidth = 200;
let outerBoxHeight = 100;
let maxInnerBoxWidth = ((outerBoxWidth / 16) | 0);

let maxInnerBoxHeight = ((outerBoxHeight / 9) | 0);

let widthLower = maxInnerBoxHeight > maxInnerBoxWidth;
if(widthLower){
  let innerBoxHeight = 9 * maxInnerBoxWidth;
  let innerBoxWidth = 17 * maxInnerBoxWidth;
}else{
  let innerBoxHeight = 9 * maxInnerBoxHeight;
  let innerBoxWidth = 17 * maxInnerBoxHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from Ouroborus I came up with the following which proves it works.

```js
const getBoxes = (outerWidth, outerHeight, innerAspectRatio) => {
  const outer = { width: outerWidth, height: outerHeight, aspectRatio: outerWidth / outerHeight }
  const inner = { width: null, height: null, aspectRatio: innerAspectRatio }
  const pillarBoxed = outer.aspectRatio > inner.aspectRatio
  inner.width = !pillarBoxed ? outer.width : outer.height * inner.aspectRatio
  inner.height = pillarBoxed ? outer.height : outer.width / inner.aspectRatio  
  return { outer, inner }
}

const adjust = 40
const boxes1 = getBoxes(160 + adjust, 90, 16/9)
const boxes2 = getBoxes(160, 90 + adjust, 16/9)

// display purposes only

const displayBoxes = (boxes, outerId, innerId) => {
  const outerEl = document.getElementById(outerId)
  outerEl.style.width = boxes.outer.width + 'px'
  outerEl.style.height = boxes.outer.height + 'px'

  const innerEl = document.getElementById(innerId)
  innerEl.style.width = boxes.inner.width + 'px'
  innerEl.style.height = boxes.inner.height + 'px'
}

displayBoxes(boxes1, 'outer1', 'inner1')
displayBoxes(boxes2, 'outer2', 'inner2')

// console.log('boxes1', boxes1)
// console.log('boxes2', boxes2)
```

```css
#outer1, #outer2 {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

#inner1, #inner2 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer1">
  <div id="inner1"></div>
</div>

<div id="outer2">
  <div id="inner2"></div>
</div>
```

To make this easy to test, I made the outer box 160x90 BUT 40px wider (first example) and 40px taller (second example). Given that this works nicely with a 16/9 aspect ratio, there should be 20px left and right in the first example and 20px above and below in the second example. Which there is!

Also, the inner box should be 160x90 in both examples, which it is!

Proof that this code works as expected.